# How does this CountDownTimer code works?

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I have seen this code on stackoverflow but I don't understand how it works, I feel so frustrated

```
      new CountDownTimer(9000000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        long millis = millisUntilFinished;
                        String time = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", 

        // From here,, I don't understand what is "going on " 
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)-
         TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),

         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis)-
TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));

        }
```

**9000000 milliseconds is : 02:30:00**

**Hour : TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)**,

9000000 milliseconds to hours is : 2,5 hours

Up to this, it's gonna show : 02:00:00 
OK, I get it

**Minutes : TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)- TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis))**

I've converted and soustracted :

TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) = 150

TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis) = 2,5

TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)) = 150

150-150 = 0 , shouldn't I have something equal to 30 ??

**Seconds : TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis)-TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)))**;

Same thing, it's gonna give me 0

How does this work ? Thank you 
}

Comment: Use a debugger.

Comment: The program works, I just don't understand what it is doing

Comment: Yes. Use a debugger.

Comment: Step through each line, one at a time, see what happens at each step...

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't know what was debugger until I've done research on it
Thank you , i'll look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it manually. First work out how many whole hours. Then subtract the number of whole hours (in milliseconds) from the total milliseconds and use that result to calculate then number of whole minutes. You can do the same for seconds (but to get the number of seconds, it’s ok to simply subtract off the whole minutes because there’s a whole number of minutes in a hour so the hours are automatically handled).

Maybe dummy variables would help:

```
WholeHours =  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)
WholeMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis))
WholeSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I know what my mistake was now
I didn't take whole numbers, which is why when I calculated it gave me 0
and it confused me so hard, thank you